# Как работает эта регулярка?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, lex

есть регулярка

`{B}*"namespace"{BN}*/[^a-z_A-Z0-9]`

где {B} это символы отступов вроде пробелов или табов, а {BN} это пробелы табы и переход на новую строку.

Мне не понятно что делает символ **/** перед `[^a-z_A-Z0-9]`.

Comment: Где вы ее используете? Возможно там этот символ что-то значит. А так, обычно он означает самого себя

Comment: @Crantisz Я увидел его в исходном коде для Flex(генератор лексических анализаторов)(язык С++) и если бы он означал сам себя то был бы в двойных кавычках "/". Он определенно что то означает но я не знаю что.

Comment: А вы пробовали этот код? Кстати, это очень похоже на ["trailing context"](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~marius/sw/flex/Flex-Regular-Expressions.html), такой аналог позитвного блока предварительного просмотра вперёд. В результате должно вернуться значение `{B}*"namespace"{BN}*`, за которым следует `[^a-z_A-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пользователь @Wiktor Stribiżew оказался прав. Этот символ нечто иное как символ завершающего контекста. О нём можно прочитать [тут](https://www.opennet.ru/soft/ruprog/lex.txt). В результате должно вернуться значение `{B}*"namespace"{BN}*`, за которым следует `[^a-z_A-Z0-9]`

> Для обработки ситуаций, требующих опережающего  просмотра, используется символ / (не путать с символом
>   ), который обозначает, что следующая за ним последовательность
>   является завершающим контекстом и ее  не  следует  сохранять  в
>   yytext[],  поскольку  она не входит в саму лексему. Правило для
>   распознавания DO в Фортране можно записать так:

```
DO/[0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+, printf("нашли DO");
```

То есть это аналог `(?=...)` в PCRE.

Comment: Исправьте, если не согласны с моей правкой.